# Add and toggle firewall rule and change DNS settings

Tags: powershell

I have been working on writing a script that will allow me (and my wife, as you'll see in some of the text in the code) to switch countries for some streaming services I use.

It first checks to see if a certain firewall rule exists and will create it if it doesn't exist. If it does exist, it will toggle the rule on or off based on the user's input so that the streaming services will have American or local (I'm not in the US) content. After that it adds/removes some DNS server addresses.

The files referenced in the script contains lists of IP addresses or network interface numbers. The interface indices are different on my computer and my wife's computer so I have one file for each of our computers that uses the computer name as its identifier.

All this can be done manually, but I wrote the script to automate the process to make life easier.

It's my first time working with Powershell and I am looking for some input on what I've written, like conventions, best practices, and/or general advice about it. The script works fine as-is, but for my own curiosity and learning, I would like to know how to improve it. If anyone has a few minutes to glance through it, I would appreciate it!

I come from a background in C# and work with content management systems specifically and like the idea of having all (or most, at least) of the static text in one place so I made the `Get-Constants` function as a way of sort of accomplishing that. This works for my script just fine, but in general are there any notable reasons I shouldn't do this?

````
Import-Module NetSecurity

$script:DNSAddressesToUse
$script:IPAddressesToBlock
$script:NetworkInterfacesToModify

Function Main
{   
    Set-StreamingCountry
}

Function Set-StreamingCountry
{
    Get-Constants

    Get-StreamingCountryChoice

    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host 'Press enter to continue'
    Read-Host
}

Function Get-Constants
{
    Set-Variable FirewallRuleName -Option Constant -Value ([string]'AmericanStreamingService') -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Variable FirewallRuleDisplayName -Option Constant -Value ([string]'American Streaming Service') -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Variable InvalidInputMessage -Option Constant -Value ([string]'Invalid input. Please try again.') -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Variable FileIsMissing -Option Constant -Value ([string]' is missing!') -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Variable ContactHusband -Option Constant -Value ([string]'Please contact your loving husband!') -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Variable DNSAddressesToUse_FileName -Option Constant -Value ([string]'DNSAddressesToUse.txt') -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Variable IPAddressesToBlock_FileName -Option Constant -Value ([string]'IPAddressesToBlock.txt') -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    Set-Variable NetworkInterfacesToModify_FileName -Option Constant -Value ([string]("$env:COMPUTERNAME" + '-NetworkInterfacesToModify.txt')) -Scope Script -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

Function Get-StreamingCountryChoice
{
    Write-Host $("You are currently using [$(Get-CurrentStreamingRegion)]")
    Write-Host ''
    Write-Host 'Would you like to watch American options or Local options?'
    Write-Host 'For American options press [a]'
    Write-Host 'For Local options press [l]'
    Write-Host 'To cancel press [c]'

    $Input = Read-Host

    If ("$Input")
    {
        Get-InformationFromConfigFiles
        CheckIfAmericanStreamingServiceFirewallRuleExists
        Set-DNSForStreaming -Choice $Input
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host $InvalidInputMessage
        Get-StreamingCountryChoice
    }
}

Function Get-CurrentStreamingRegion
{
    Get-Constants
    Get-InformationFromConfigFiles
    $dnsInformation = Get-DNSClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $script:NetworkInterfacesToModify -AddressFamily IPv4

    $matches = 0

    foreach($dnsEntry in $dnsInformation)
    {
        $differencesBetweenComputerDNSAddressesAndStreamingDNSAddresses = compare-object $dnsEntry.serveraddresses $script:dnsaddressestouse -passthru
        if (-Not $differencesBetweenComputerDNSAddressesAndStreamingDNSAddresses)
        {
            $matches++
        }
    }

    if ($matches -eq $script:NetworkInterfacesToModify.length)
    {
        return 'American'
    }
    else
    {
        return 'Local'
    }
}

Function Get-InformationFromConfigFiles
{
    Function Get-DNSAddresesToUse
    {
        $DNSAddressesToUse_Exists = Test-Path -LiteralPath $DNSAddressesToUse_FileName

        If ($DNSAddressesToUse_Exists)
        {
            $script:DnsAddressesToUse = Get-Content $DNSAddressesToUse_FileName
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Host ($DNSAddressesToUse_FileName + $FileIsMissing)
            Write-Host $ContactHusband
            Exit
        }
    }

    Function Get-IPAddressesToBlock
    {
        $IPAddressesToBlock_Exists = Test-Path -LiteralPath $IPAddressesToBlock_FileName

        If ($IPAddressesToBlock_Exists)
        {
            $script:IPAddressesToBlock = Get-Content $IPAddressesToBlock_FileName
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Host ($IPAddressesToBlock_FileName + $FileIsMissing)
            Write-Host $ContactHusband
            Exit
        }
    }

    Function Get-NetworkInterfacesToModify
    {
        $NetworkInterfacesToModify_Exists = Test-Path -LiteralPath $NetworkInterfacesToModify_FileName

        If ($NetworkInterfacesToModify_Exists)
        {
            $script:NetworkInterfacesToModify = Get-Content $NetworkInterfacesToModify_FileName
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Host ($NetworkInterfacesToModify_FileName + $FileIsMissing)
            Write-Host $ContactHusband
            Exit
        }
    }

    Get-DNSAddresesToUse
    Get-IPAddressesToBlock
    Get-NetworkInterfacesToModify
}

Function CheckIfAmericanStreamingServiceFirewallRuleExists
{
    $DoesFirewallRuleExist = Get-NetFirewallRule -Name $FirewallRuleName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if (-Not $DoesFirewallRuleExist)
    {
        CreateFirewallRuleForAmericanStreamingService
    }
}

Function CreateFirewallRuleForAmericanStreamingService
{
    Function Write-Host {} #Silences output from New-NetFirewallRule cmdlet

    New-NetFirewallRule `
    -Name $FirewallRuleName `
    -DisplayName $FirewallRuleDisplayName `
    -Direction Outbound `
    -Action Block `
    -Enabled True `
    -RemoteAddress $IPAddressesToBlock
}

Function Set-DNSForStreaming
{
    Param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, Position=0)]
        [char] $Choice
    )

    Function Set-AmericanDNS
    {
        foreach ($networkInterfaceIndex in $NetworkInterfacesToModify)
        {
            Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $networkInterfaceIndex -ServerAddresses $DNSAddressesToUse
        }

        Set-NetFirewallRule -Name $FirewallRuleName -Enabled True
    }

    Function Set-LocalDNS
    {
        foreach ($networkInterfaceIndex in $NetworkInterfacesToModify)
        {
            Set-DnsClientServerAddress -InterfaceIndex $networkInterfaceIndex -ResetServerAddresses
        }

        Set-NetFirewallRule -Name $FirewallRuleName -Enabled False
    }

    If ($Choice -eq 'a')
    {
        Set-AmericanDNS
    }
    ElseIf ($Choice -eq 'l')
    {
        Set-LocalDNS
    }
    ElseIf ($Choice -eq 'c')
    {
        Write-Host 'Goodbye!'
        Exit
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host $InvalidInputMessage
        Get-StreamingCountryChoice
    }
}

Main
```
````